# Preventing a new page from opening when href is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, excel

My goal is to download an html table to an excel file that is automatically downloaded when a button is clicked.  The button calls the function `fnExportExcel()`.

I am using the following code to export an html table as an excel file:

```
function fnExportExcel() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    var postfix = month + "." + day + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
    //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('datatable');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'MachineReport_' + postfix + '.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The `e.preventDefault()` isn't working, but the excel file is downloading.  A new page is loading and coming up not found. Is there another way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Calling `.preventDefault()` only makes sense inside an event handler.

Comment: So instead of doing 'a.click(); e.preventDefault();' would I do something like: 'a.addEventListender("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });'.  Because when I do this it doesn't download the file anymore.

Comment: what is the thing you want to do? "excel file is downloading" - so is that a good or a bad thing?

Comment: That is a good thing.  I want the file to download, not try to load a new page.  So it's doing both right now and I only want it downloading the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2s6020w/).

```
let link = document.getElementById("myLink"); //Here write the ID of your <a> element.
link.addEventListener("mouseover", link.showHref = function(e) {
  let target = e.target || this;
  if (link.mouseDown)
    link.mouseDown = false;
  else
    target.href = target._href || target.href;
});
link.addEventListener("mousemove", link.showHref);
link.addEventListener("mouseup", link.showHrefForced = function(e) {
    link.mouseDown = false;
});
link.addEventListener("touchend", link.showHrefForced);
link.addEventListener("mousedown", link.cancelHref = function(e) {
  let target = e.target || this;
  if (target.href !== "javascript:void(0)")
    target._href = target.href;
  target.href = "javascript:void(0)";
  link.mouseDown = true;
});
link.addEventListener("touchstart", link.cancelHref);
link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  link.showHref(e);
  let target = e.target || this;
    let url = target._href || target.href;
  let newLink = document.createElement("a");
  newLink.download = link.name;
  newLink.href = url;
  newLink.click();
});
```

The solution mainly consists in disabling the click of `<a>` element programmatically, avoiding to browse the page, whereas a hidden `<a>` element (not added to a parent) is created and its click is performed to download the URI silently.

Comment: Doing this doesn't allow me to download the excel file, which is what I need.

Comment: Do you want the link working but not showing another page?

Comment: Yes.  I want it to stay on the same page

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot!

Comment: is there a reason why this wouldn't work if my table is in an iframe? I have another webpage I want to do the same thing in, but the only difference is that it is in an iframe and it isn't working the same.

Answer (score 2):

calling `e.preventDefault()` suggests that `e` is already an argument within a callback function.

You will need to make an event listener for the `click` in order to get your `e` argument from the `event` callback.

```js
let anchorTag = document.querySelector('a')

anchorTag.addEventListener('click', e => { //notice the passing of `e` (this stands for event)
  e.preventDefault() //preventing the event here
  //logic goes here
})
```

```html
<a href="/my/url">click here for nothing to happen</a>
```